# vector projection in three dimensional space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to find the projection "d" of vector "P" on "P2"[image], any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
    \definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, quotes}  
  \begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{80}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

 
\draw[-stealth,color=myblue] (O) -- (P);
\tdplotsetcoord{P2}{0.9}{60}{80}
\draw[-stealth,color=myblue] (O) -- (P2);
\tdplotsetcoord{P3}{0.6}{60}{80}
\pic [ang, "$\phi$"] {angle = P2--O--P};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use mathematical formula to derive projection.

> length of vector obtained by projection of P over P2 is |P|cos(phi).

So `\tdplotsetcoord{P5}{0.4*sqrt(3)}{60}{80}` (0.8*cos(60-30)) is the projected point on P2.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

 
\draw[-stealth,color=myblue] (O) -- (P);
\tdplotsetcoord{P2}{0.9}{60}{80}
\draw[-stealth,color=myblue] (O) -- (P2);
\tdplotsetcoord{P3}{0.6}{60}{80}
\pic [ang, "$\phi$"] {angle = P2--O--P};

\tdplotsetcoord{P5}{0.4*sqrt(3)}{60}{80}
\draw[-stealth,color=red, dashed] (O) -- (P5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: so there is no comands like pxy ?

Comment: you can define it but there is no as I am aware.

Comment: There is another way posted in [teample](https://texample.net) that is you should define a new coordinates system then project your vector in that coordinates system. for example: `\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (.5,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x'$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,.5,0) node[anchor=west]{$y'$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,.5) node[anchor=south]{$z'$};

\draw[-stealth,color=blue,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (.2,.2,.2);`

Comment: See the end of page [here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/)

Comment: Is that simple or mine?

Comment: and a related [post.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459213/108724)